# How get pubDate of channel using SimplePie?

Tags: php, rss, simplepie

I have next rss:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Новини на tsn.ua</title>
        <link>http://tsn.ua/</link>
        <description>TSN.UA RSS feed</description>
        <language>uk-ukr</language>
        <pubDate>Fri, 04 Dec 2015 20:00:06 +0200</pubDate>
        <ttl>300</ttl>
        <image>
            <url>http://tsn.ua/static/img/tsn_top_logo_rss.gif</url>
            <title>Новини на tsn.ua - </title>
            <link>http://tsn.ua/</link>
        </image>
    </channel>
    </rss>
```

... etc
How I can get GENERAL pubDate of DOCUMENT using SimplePie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) parses the xml:

```
$xmlx='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <channel>
        <title>Новини на tsn.ua</title>
        <link>http://tsn.ua/</link>
        <description>TSN.UA RSS feed</description>
        <language>uk-ukr</language>
        <pubDate>Fri, 04 Dec 2015 20:00:06 +0200</pubDate>
        <ttl>300</ttl>
        <image>
            <url>http://tsn.ua/static/img/tsn_top_logo_rss.gif</url>
            <title>Новини на tsn.ua - </title>
            <link>http://tsn.ua/</link>
        </image>
    </channel>
    </rss>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlx);
if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML: ";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "<br>", $error->message;
    }
} else {
    var_dump($xml->channel->pubDate);
}
```

P.S: Next time please post the whole XML or a valid one

P.S 2: You can parse the date by using [this](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.date-create-from-format.php) function

Comment: Thank you, @KA_lin . It`s very simple and convenient method. Thanks for the advice